# Python code being displayed on clients instead of executed

Tags: php, html

I have a site where the homepage is an HTML form asking for name and password, then clicking submit launches a PHP script to read a database and validate the credentials.  I recently "updated" by replacing PHP with Python.  For a few people, when they click submit the Python script dumps to their screen.  For most people, it works fine.  I found where I had `charset=windows-1252`, so I changed that to be `charset=utf-8`; no luck.  I saw a post about a `.htaccess file`; no luck.  The failing systems seem to have a common thread of Chrome on non-Windows devices (Samsung tablet; Mac; iPhone with Chrome).  Others with iPad's have success, and Windows devices work.  My iPhone with Safari works.  I'm completely stumped.  Fortunately, I still have all the PHP scripts, so I might have to revert back.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: You'll need to post more information about your setup for us to help you.

Comment: I know.  The files are on a hosted site, so I don't have much info about the specifics.  Is there anything specific I can ask the site support team?

Comment: I did `. htaccess` rewrites on a PHP server by using Passenger (Ruby mod works with Python) -- quite brittle. If you have a shared server this can be a hard task. If using a VENV  there are concerns relating to how the server works.